# Auto click button if doesn't has class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to fire and auto click on a `a href` if it doesn't has the class `.active`. My goal is to create something like Tom from myspace to automatically add a member as a friend. But this code seems to ignore if the button is already clicked `(has the class .active already)` and it auto clicks again when I refresh the page. here's my code

```
if ($(".follow-1:not(.active)")) {
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('.follow-1').click(SK_registerFollow(1));
    });
} else {
    // do nothing   
}
```

I also tried this but it was not successful as well:

```
if ($('.follow-1').hasClass("active")) {
    // do nothing
} else {
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('.follow-1').click(SK_registerFollow(1));
    });
}
```

------------- **UPDATED** ---------------

The HTML code is this:

```
<a class="follow-1" onclick="SK_registerFollow(1);">follow</a>
```

Comment: jQuery returns a function so `if ($(".follow-1:not(.active)"))` will always be true. If you want to click if it *doesn't* have a class, you'd need to negate `if ($('.follow-1').hasClass("active"))` -> `if(!$(".follow-1") ......`

Comment: Using `jQuery('.follow-1').click(SK_registerFollow(1));` will bind the result of `SK_registerFollow(1)` function to click handler of `jQuery('.follow-1')`

Comment: I don't think the `jQuery(function(){...});` that is wrapping your click, is necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK there's quite a few things wrong here so I'll inline comment:

```
// $() will always return a function, so this will always fire
if ($(".follow-1:not(.active)")) {
    // This is waiting for a document.ready, so you need to do this on the outside
    /// of your code
    jQuery(function(){
        // This will execute SK_registerFollow immediately
        // and send the result to your handler. Probably not what you want
        jQuery('.follow-1').click(SK_registerFollow(1));
    });
} else {
    // No need to ever have a block which 'does nothing'
    // do nothing   
}
```

Here's a fixed version:

```
// Wait for DOM to become ready
$(function() {
    // Store a reference to the link, so we don't need to search for it twice
    var $follow = $(".follow-1");
    // Test to see if the link has the active class
    if (!$follow.hasClass("active")) {
        $follow.click(); // This will trigger the appropriate onclick handler
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8c37rtp5/)

Comment: OMG you are my savior!! This works perfectly! :D Thank you very much and thanks for the detailed explanation as well

Comment: Hey, @RGraham I was trying to implement this solution with [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) can you help me out with this giving me a jsfiddle example or something?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$('.follow-1').hasClass("active")) {
    // do nothing
} else {
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('.follow-1').click(SK_registerFollow(1));
    });
}
```

Use not equal to operator and try.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jQuery('.follow-1').not('.active').click(SK_registerFollow(1));
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/1gqwqx5y/)

Comment: It's still always clicking it anyways... I wrapped it inside of: `$(document).ready(function(){ Your Code Here });` and all, but still the same :\ isn't there a workaround way for this? maybe with a cookie? The thing is idk how to set those up as well